# PrimeFaces and JQuery: resource ordering

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have a problem with the order of JQuery imports.
In the head section I do:

```
<h:head>
<f:facet name="first">
     <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
</f:facet>
<f:facet name="middle">
  <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" target="head" />
</f:facet>
...
```

The first time my page is loaded everything seems correct, especially the jquery/jquery-plugins order:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head id="j_idt2">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-aristo" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/components.css.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/css/default/core.css.jsf?ln=bsf" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/css/bsf.css.jsf?ln=bsf" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/js/html5shiv.js.jsf?ln=bsf"></script><script src="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/js/respond.js.jsf?ln=bsf"></script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/core.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script>
...
```

On the page are buttons like

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-mini btn-default"
   actionListener="#{testController['filterTable']}">
   <i class="fa fa-refresh"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

After pressing one of them the page is loaded again with errors in JS-Console like

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at tbmDisposition-aendernPF.jsf:3
VM219 jquery-plugins.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&v=6.0:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at VM219 jquery-plugins.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&v=6.0:5
    at VM219 jquery-plugins.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&v=6.0:5
```

And when you look at the generated html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head id="j_idt2">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-aristo" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/css/default/core.css.jsf?ln=bsf" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/css/bsf.css.jsf?ln=bsf" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/js/html5shiv.js.jsf?ln=bsf"></script><script src="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/js/respond.js.jsf?ln=bsf"></script><![endif]-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/components.css.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/installateurportal/javax.faces.resource/core.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0"></script>
...
```

You can see that jquery-plugins is **above** jquery which causes the described error.

Of course I tried various alternatives in the head section without success, so any help would be appreciated.

Version informations

PrimeFacs: 6.0

JSF: 1.2_15-jbossorg-2

Server: jboss-as-7.1.2.Final

Greetings
Kai

**Update:**
Debugging the HeadRenderer I found out that the HeadRenderer doesn't seem to be responsible for JQuery at all.
It must have something to do with ResourceDependencies of the Widget and how they are rendered.
Does anyone know which renderer might be responsible for ResourceDependencies?

**Update 2:** 
Besides I am using BootsFaces for the layout. Now I learned that BootsFaces has its own JQuery and resource optimization as well ...

**Update 3:**
In the ResourceFileComparator of BootsFaces the JS files will be renamed like

```
if (name.contains("jquery-ui")) name = "2.js"; // make it the second JS file
else if (name.contains("jquery")) name = "1.js"; // make it the first JS file
```

But in my case the name for jquery-ui is: "jquery/jquery-plugins.js"
=> Both "jquery/jquery.js" and "jquery/jquery-plugins.js" will be renamed to "1.js"

Comment: Are you sure you're running JSF 1.2? Personally I don't add the files I want into facets, because I am always not 100% sure where they will be, I'd put them at the bottom of the <head> manually and wait to see when primefaces does it's auto injection. Alternatively you could turn off PrimeFaces themes etc and do it all yourself.

Comment: The maven dependency says 
<version>1.2_15-jbossorg-2</version>
But it is JSF 2.1.
How can I then do it all myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started an issue at BootsFaces-OSP (https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/640) and found a workaround (described in the issue).
So now it works for me.